# Earliest and latest record for an id with a condition on a column value

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a json data which has to be converted into columns, and I am able to successfully do that and it leads me to something as below:

| id | phone | country | country_code | status | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 123 | India | 91 | open | 2021-09-01 |
| abc | 123 | India | 91 | closed | 2021-09-02 |
| xyz | 456 | India | 91 | open | 2021-09-01 |
| xyz | 456 | India | 91 | closed | 2021-09-02 |
| xyz | 456 | India | 91 | open | 2021-09-03 |
| ijk | 789 | India | 91 | open | 2021-09-01 |
| ijk | 789 | India | 91 | closed | 2021-09-02 |
| ijk | 789 | India | 91 | open | 2021-09-03 |
| ijk | 789 | India | 91 | closed | 2021-09-04 |
| suv | 000 | US | 1 | Open | 2021-09-05 |

This is a status data which says when the activity for a certain task is open or closed. An activity that is closed can re-open too and get re-closed too or may stay open. But the values of the status key is open/closed only.

Now, what I need is the earliest open timestamp and the latest closed timestamp. This will tell me when they opened the activity for the first time and when was it last closed.

The result should be like:

| id | phone | country | country_code | status | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 123 | India | 91 | open | 2021-09-01 |
| abc | 123 | India | 91 | closed | 2021-09-02 |
| xyz | 456 | India | 91 | open | 2021-09-01 |
| xyz | 456 | India | 91 | closed | 2021-09-02 |
| ijk | 789 | India | 91 | open | 2021-09-01 |
| ijk | 789 | India | 91 | closed | 2021-09-04 |
| suv | 000 | US | 1 | Open | 2021-09-05 |

A status = open can only follow with a status = closed. It cannot re-open without a close but it can stay open and never get closed.

For id=abc there is one open followed by closed status, so I need those two; for id = xyz there is a re-open but I don't care and still need the earliest open and the only ever closed. For id = ijk there is a re-open and a re-closed so I need the earliest open and the latest closed. For id = suv there was never a close so it should just return that only open record. (Only id is unique and cannot be null here. Even though the phone looks unique too but it can be null also)

So, basically there could be only max 2 records for any id (1 if there was never a closed status associated to it). The first record for any i is for status = open and the earliest timestamp. But, when the status is closed and it has multiple closes then the last one for that particular id.

I have to put the data in a schema and I can do this using rank clause easily, but is this possible in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can groupby, filter, then take first/last as follows:

```
# copy, clean df
# df = pd.read_clipboard("\s\s+")
# df["status"] = df.status.str.lower()
# df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)
# df = df.sort_values("timestamp")

# this stores the original index as a column, creates a new
df = df.reset_index()

df_open = df[df.status == "open"].groupby(["id"], as_index=False).first()
df_closed = df[df.status == "closed"].groupby(["id"], as_index=False).last()

# discard the temp index, set back to original index    
sol = pd.concat([df_open, df_closed]).set_index("index", drop=True).sort_index()
```

output:

```
        id  phone country  country_code  status  timestamp
index
0      abc    123   India            91    open 2021-09-01
1      abc    123   India            91  closed 2021-09-02
2      xyz    456   India            91    open 2021-09-01
3      xyz    456   India            91  closed 2021-09-02
5      ijk    789   India            91    open 2021-09-01
8      ijk    789   India            91  closed 2021-09-04
9      suv      0      US             1    open 2021-09-05
```

Comment: I don't want the id to be turned into an index. It must stay as a row with the index being row numbers auto-generated. I have to put this inside a sql database. Also, thanks for last function. I was trying a different way with rank and picking the earliest odd number and the last even number but this will be more efficient. Can you keep the structure same as the question?

Comment: sure, gimme a sec